# How to write efficient Junit Test cases in Java?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

This is the simple code that I have, and I have to write a jUnit test case for the same.

```
public String deletes() throws Exception {
        String deleteSql = "select * from test";
        if (isMultiTenant) {
            return deleteSql = deleteSql + "and id = ? ";
        } else {
            return deleteSql;
        }
    }
```

so I did it in this way, but somewhere it doesn't look like a good test case its look like simply comparing string between two.
Is there any other way to write test case more meaningful

Comment: Don't assert _what_ the query is.  Assert what it does.  Pass it to a test database, and verify you get back the right results.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the unit tests consist of three separate steps:

1. Data preparation
2. Execution
3. Results assertion

There are a lot of people who prefer a test consisted only of the assertion(s):

```
@Test
public void updateSqlTest() {
    assertEquals(
        "select * from test",
        test.updateSQL()
    );
}
```

This is one way of "looking" the test better in terms of formatting. That's all to discuss here as this kind of *test makes no sense to me*.

**Remember:** Don't aim for 100 % code coverage but covering the most important and business-related code. A more meaningful test would be:

- Mocking the repository/DAO layer (accessing the database) and test the service layer performing business logic.
- Running in-memory database for the purpose of testing (with Spring Boot usually H2 is used as it works very well), fetch and update the data from the database and assert the results.

The test you wrote makes no sense to me. I'd test out the behavior of the SQL query itself and the related business logic that uses it.

Comment: I have edited the question can u pls help me with boolean case @nikolas charalambidis

Comment: My answer doesn’t change with your edit. Focus on the 2nd half of the answer.